# Android/Google Analytics: How to get string from the EditText and send it to Google Analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics

I'm messing around "Google Analytics" for tracking user behavior. I'm able to track pageViews and click of the button.

I'm facing problem in sending the string from the edittext on onClick() method to analytic server.

I have tried using :

```
tracker.trackEvent(arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

But no success. Please guide me where am I doing wrong.

Here is the code in which I'm taking string from the edittext and on OnClick(), I want to send it to the server:

```
tracker.trackEvent("Application Android",
                    "viewPageFromCategory", txt, 0);
            tracker.dispatch();
```

Here txt is the string from edittext.

Comment: 1) make sure the tracking of the Activity itself is working. 2) trackevent should then work. have you read this guide? https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide its pretty much the same on android but you dont have the bounce rate boolean. http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/tracking-user-behavior-with-google-analytics-sdk-for-android/ gives a nice overview also and finally https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/devguide has good example code.

Comment: Ya tracking of the activity is confirmed by using trackPageview(). I came across all the tutorials which you have provided but my trackevent() method is not showing my data on the analytics account. Can you give me some code idea, that how to do that?

Comment: can you post your code that is not working ?

Comment: Check my edited question with the code.

Comment: that snippet looks right. do you use the same tracker as for the pageview and is the session still open? are you dispatching your pageview beforehand? have you set a custom timer when to dispatch?

Comment: Ya on OnCreate() after pageview I have dispatched the tracker. What should I do? when to dispatch the tracker to work them properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing `0` for the event "value".  I think that means the event occurred 0 times, and so there is nothing to track.

See https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide#Values:

> The value is interpreted as a number and the report adds the total values based on each event count

If you enable verbose debugging of the GA library, you can see in a bit more detail what (if anything) is being pushed up to Google:

```
tracker = GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance();
tracker.setDebug(true); /* send all updates to the log */
tracker.setDryRun(true); /* Do not actually send updates on the network */
```